# How to prevent select after insert in hibernate 3

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

We are using hibernate 3 to insert some values, just plain bean objects. However, this specific process does not have a SELECT privilege on the same table that it does the INSERT. So, what bothers us, is the SELECT statement that is done right after the INSERT. I am just guessing it is done to retrieve the generated ID and may be some other stuff. But, what if I in my code don't need that? Can I somehow state to hibernate 'just insert this entity and do not re-select the generated ID' ? The main point is that this table is only allowed to be inserted into by this user, but its not allowed for SELECT.
Thank you.

Comment: 'I am just guessing it is done to retrieve the generated ID' - do we really need to guess? Could you please enable SQL logging and post the results here? It would also help if you posted the entity mapping and the method used for inserting entities

Comment: I will rephrase - There is a very simple java bean. We tried with persist and save and looking in the SQL log there is always an insert statement that followed by a select statement from the same table.

Comment: I will rephrase - post the SQL from the logs, the entity mapping and your code for inserting the entity